# Reading uncommitted transactions in Android

Tags: java, sql, android, database, sqlite

I have database heavy operations happening, which adds around 10,000 records to my Database. Since this could take a very long time, it would be better to use transactions.

```
db.startTransaction();
....
do write operations.
....
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

Now, I have some read operations inside the transactions, and since the inserts are not committed until endTransaction, those records are not fetched. I have heard about something called Transaction Isolation Levels, which enables us to read dirty (uncommitted) records as well. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Transactions can be nested. What's the problem here?

Comment: The problem is whatever I insert is not 'readable' until I commit it. Because read happens only from the actual database, but not the dirty inserts. I guess..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that by default you will be able to read records which are yet to be committed. Though this fails if you are using `SQliteOpenHelper`. This is because `SQliteOpenHelper` gives 2 separate handled (read& write) and uncommitted writes won't be available for read from the other handle. 
So, if you want to read uncommited records, use `SQLiteDatabase` class.

Comment: You can read on the writable handle as well -- no need to use a different class

Answer (score 3):

I would advise call SQLite's SQL statement pragma:

```
database.execSQL("PRAGMA read_uncommitted = true;");
```

This statement says that queries will use transaction isolation level READ_UNCOMMITTED instead of READ_SERIALIZABLE (default SQLite's mode).

Look for instance [here](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_read_uncommitted)

Comment: Won't this make uncommitted writes visible to all readers? I doubt most people want that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this

```
// outer transaction
db.startTransaction();
....

    //roll out a new transaction
    db.startTransaction();
    ....
    do write operations.
    ....
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();// <-- you do commint inside of this transaction

    // you can read data from here on from the previous committed transaction

....
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Also, did you miss an endTransaction() for the inner Transaction?

Comment: Yes I leaved out that intentionally `When the outer transaction is ended all of the work done in that transaction and all of the nested transactions will be committed or rolled back. The changes will be rolled back if any transaction is ended without being marked as clean (by calling setTransactionSuccessful). Otherwise they will be committed.` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()

Comment: But, the documentation also says, "Do not do any more database work between calling setTransactionSuccessful and calling endTransaction..."  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setTransactionSuccessful()

Comment: That won't happen because you another `setTransactionSuccessful` just before the last `endTransaction` call. The manual says that between those two do not do anything.