# I got a Cursor from database, then modify a row in the database , the data in the Cursor will change or not?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Assume that I get a `Cursor` by `db.query()`.
Then I modify a field in a row by `db.update()`,and this row is included by `Cursor` queried before.
Data in this Cursor will change or not?

like this:

```
Cursor cur = db.query("[some parameter can get row 0]"); 
cur.moveToFirst; 
int a = cur.getInt(0);
db.update("[some parameter can modify row 0 col 0]");
int b = cur.getInt(0);
```

Is (a==b) true or false ?

======  edited 2012.10.1 =========
I am not a pro-programmer,and too busy to code in these days.
If I make you unhappy ,I am very sorry.
Finally , I get a holiday of a week, haha .

I do some coding like this:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper h = null;
SQLiteDatabase db = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    h=new SQLiteOpenHelper(this, "test.db", null,1){

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE t1 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT )");
            arg0.execSQL("INSERT INTO t1 (name) VALUES ('name_wrong')");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};

    db=h.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cur =  db.query("t1", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    String s1=cur.getString(1);

    db.execSQL("UPDATE t1 SET name = 'name_right'");

    String s2=cur.getString(1);
    Log.d("","s1 = "+s1);
    Log.d("","s2 = "+s2);
    Log.d("","s1 == s2 is "+s1.equals(s2));
    Log.d("","requery...");
    cur =  db.query("t1", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    s2=cur.getString(1);
    Log.d("","s1 = "+s1);
    Log.d("","s2 = "+s2);
    Log.d("","s1 == s2 is "+s1.equals(s2));
}
```

And logcat say that:

`10-01 03:11:28.356: D/(1514): s1 = name_wrong`
`10-01 03:11:28.356: D/(1514): s2 = name_wrong`
`10-01 03:11:28.356: D/(1514): s1 == s2 is true`
`10-01 03:11:28.356: D/(1514): requery...`
`10-01 03:11:28.356: D/(1514): s1 = name_wrong`
`10-01 03:11:28.356: D/(1514): s2 = name_right`
`10-01 03:11:28.356: D/(1514): s1 == s2 is false`

So I think I get the answer
Thank you all guys.

Comment: Here's some related dicussion on transaction isolation levels: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314371/reading-uncommitted-transactions-in-android

Comment: 1. the database does not commit until endTransaction() is called.       2. this seems like something that would be rather trivial to test and confirm for yourself, and probably get an answer faster than posting here.

Comment: That's a slippery road, anyway. I don't think there's any specification or standard on that.  The answer is buried somewhere in the SQLite related code.  It's all implementation dependent and thus volatile: it can change in some future version, regardless of autocommit and isolation levels.  Doesn't look like a good solution, no matter what an experiment would give you today.

Comment: I'm noob in programming(and even in English).I have not any idea about how Sqlite database works. So I can not catch you full.stack.ex. (T T)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you don't see any changes except if you re-query.
2. cursors are not live. that is, the moment you have a cursor loaded, it has nothing to do with the database anymore. it is just a data structure (like an array).

*Basically*

> Is (a==b) true or false ?

false

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cursor would have the change, as cursors are just pointers to a record/data set. I do not believe that they are an actual content based data structure by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

https://sqlite.org/isolation.html

If changes occur on the same database connection after a query starts running but before the query completes, then it is undefined whether or not the query will see those changes.

If changes occur on the same database connection after a query starts running but before the query completes, then the query might return a changed row more than once, or it might return a row that was previously deleted.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17707733)

Comment: well, from the official sqlite document's view point, if the query start, but not complete, any changes to the database, it is undefined for query result whether or not will see those changes.